# What's the lowest temperature a tardigrade can remain active at?

Tags: zoology, metabolism, ecology, temperature, environment

There's a lot of information floating around the net about how tough they are & what they can survive, like [*"We now know that some tardigrades can tolerate being frozen to -272.8 °C"*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/earth/story/20150313-the-toughest-animals-on-earth).

But any details on the environmental ranges they can actually be active in rather than what extremes they can survive in one or other of their various states of metabolic suspension seem entirely absent for the casual (& not so casual, I've spent hours looking for these details) surfer.

So does anyone out there know what the temperature range of an active (rather than dormant) tardigrade is, with specific reference to the lower end of the scale.